# Scale points in a SvgDocument using vvvv/SVG

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, svg, vector-graphics

So as you can see from my code below I intend to load a svg file(Which works fine) and then scale the svg polygon(which is what I cant figure out). I have tried setting path points and looked around the library for helper classes, but I'm not getting anywhere.

I just realized this might be a two part question, because I am assuming that the center is 0,0 in the code below. So how do I Scale Vectors on a center point(where the center is(width/2,height/2).) or how to use this SVG library to do so.

I am using this library: https://github.com/vvvv/SVG

```
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(sContent);

                var svgDocument = SvgDocument.Open(doc);
                //PointF center = new PointF(svgDocument.ViewBox.Height / 2, svgDocument.ViewBox.Width / 2);
                for (int i = 0; i < svgDocument.Path.PathPoints.Count(); i++)
                {
                    svgDocument.Path.PathPoints[i].X = svgDocument.Path.PathPoints[i].X * .5f;
                    svgDocument.Path.PathPoints[i].Y = svgDocument.Path.PathPoints[i].Y * .5f;
                }
```

Hexagon in svg, in case anyone needs one or something:

```
<polygon fill="#008000" 
    stroke="#000000" 
    stroke-width="7" 
    id="hex"
     points="382.67657470703125,2.646820068359375 509.3531494140625,256 382.67657470703125,509.3531799316406 129.32342529296875,509.3531799316406 2.6468505859375,256 129.32342529296875,2.646820068359375 "/>
```

Edit:
Changed my search criteria and found out how to scale points. but not how to modify SvgDocument
[Scaling vectors from a center point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783389/scaling-vectors-from-a-center-point)

Comment: I'm having same problem. Amazing that such an extensive library has no documentation or usage examples. Curious if you were able to get transforms/scaling working with this library?

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit old but the solution is:

```
if(svgDoc.Transforms == null)
{
    svgDoc.Transforms = new Svg.Transforms.SvgTransformCollection();
}

svgDoc.Transforms.Add(new Svg.Transforms.SvgScale(0.5f));
```